# Why does Minimize return a wrong answer?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to find the minimum of the following function, but get a wrong result. What am I doing wrong?

```
data = {0.01189, 0.00097, 0.0007, 0.0005, 0.00042, 0.00038, 0.00033, 
0.00031, 0.00026, 0.00022, 0.00021, 0.0002, 0.00024, 0.0003, 
0.00044, 0.00062, 0.0008, 0.00091, 0.00105, 0.00112, 0.00124, 
0.00129, 0.00134, 0.0014, 0.00146, 0.00152, 0.00159, 0.00166, 
0.00174, 0.00182, 0.0019, 0.00199, 0.00209, 0.00219, 0.0023, 
0.00242, 0.00254, 0.00268, 0.00282, 0.00296, 0.00312, 0.00329, 
0.00346, 0.00365, 0.00385, 0.00406, 0.00428, 0.00451, 0.00476, 
0.00502, 0.00529, 0.00558, 0.00589, 0.00621, 0.00655, 0.0069, 
0.00728, 0.00767, 0.00808, 0.00851, 0.00895, 0.00942, 0.00991, 
0.01041, 0.01093, 0.01148, 0.01204, 0.01261, 0.0132, 0.01381, 
0.01443, 0.01506, 0.01569, 0.01634, 0.01698, 0.01762, 0.01826, 
0.01888, 0.01949, 0.02008, 0.02064, 0.02116, 0.02165, 0.02208, 
0.02246, 0.02277, 0.02301, 0.02317, 0.02324, 0.02321, 0.02308, 
0.02285, 0.0225, 0.02203, 0.02145, 0.02076, 0.01995, 0.01903, 
0.01802, 0.01691, 0.01574, 0.0145, 0.01322, 0.01191, 0.01061, 
0.00932, 0.00808, 0.00689, 0.00578, 0.00476, 0.00385, 0.00304, 
0.00235, 0.00177, 0.00129, 0.00092, 0.00063, 0.00042, 0.00026, 
0.00016};
g[x_] = Indexed[data, x + 1];

Veibull[x_] = k*x^n*Exp[-k/(n + 1)*x^(n + 1)]
resultV[k_, n_] = Sum[(g[i] - Veibull[i])^2, {i, 0, 119}];
NMinimize[{resultV[k, n], n \[Element] PositiveIntegers, k > 0}, {k, n}]
```

This code give me next result:

```
{0.00557318, {k -> 0.00021559, n -> 1}}
```

But i know more optimal point:

```
{0.00170, {k -> 6*10^(-10), n -> 4}}
```

Comment: Use the method "RandomSearch": `NMinimize[{resultV[k, n], n \[Element] PositiveIntegers, k > 0}, {k,  n}, Method -> "RandomSearch"]`

Comment: If you do: tab = Table[{n, NMinimize[{resultV[k, n], k > 0}, k]}, {n, 1, 10}]
then you can see that the 4th one is the smallest.

Comment: @bill s: Did you look at my answer before having posted your comment : `0.00118334<0.00170`? `NMinimize` without options may find a local minimum an this is in accordance with the documentation.

Comment: @user64494 - your answer is not the smallest. Here is the output of the 3rd and 4th elements of tab from my previous comment: {3, {0.00118334, {k -> 6.59549*10^-8}}}, {4, {0.000430963, {k -> 9.22782*10^-10}}}. Note that the 4th one is smaller than the 3rd.

Comment: Do you correctly define `Veibull[x_] = k*x^n*Exp[-k/(n + 1)*x^(n + 1)]`? [ The documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeibullDistribution.html?q=WeibullDistribution) says that `PDF[WeibullDistribution[\[Alpha], \[Beta]], x]` is $$\begin{cases}
 \frac{\alpha  e^{-\left(\frac{x}{\beta }\right)^{\alpha }}
   \left(\frac{x}{\beta }\right)^{\alpha -1}}{\beta } & x>0 \\
 0 & \text{True}
\end{cases}
, $$

Comment: @bill s: You are right. However the PDF of the Weibull distribution is iincorrectly written down in the question.

Comment: @user64494 - My answer was using the definition of Veibull[x_] given by the OP. If that changes, then likely the minimum will change!

Comment: I'd like to add that doing a least-square-error fit to a PDF is generally a very bad way to fit a distribution to data. Where does this data come from to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

Redefine `Veibull`

```
Veibull[x_] = Which[x>0,  k*x^n*Exp[-k/(n + 1)*x^(n + 1)],True,0]
```

Looking at

```
ParametricPlot3D[
Evaluate[Table[{n, k, resultV[k, n]}, {n, 1, 10}]], {k, 0, 3 },AxesLabel -> {n, k} ] // Quiet
```

[image]

we see possible local minima and maxima for `n>=3`.

The following plot

```
Plot3D[ {resultV[0, n], resultV[k, n]} , {k, 0, 1 }, {n, 1, 5}, 
PlotPoints -> 100 , AxesLabel -> {"k", "n", "resultV[k,n]"}, 
PlotStyle -> Opacity[.2], Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

suggests the global minimum `0<=k<=1` is independent of n and evaluates to  `k==0,n,resultV[0, n]==0.0156663`

Comment: Can we compare the values of these minima from the picture? I think no. Therefore, the above picture is of a little utility.

Comment: I think yes: We see a set of different n-values.Plot includes local and global minima.

Comment: Can you write down these values and their positions? TIA.

Comment: How do you obtain `k==0,n,resultV[0, n]==0.0156663` from the picture? How about `{0.00118334, {k -> 6.59549*10^-8, n -> 3}}` in my answer?

Comment: 3D-plot let me assume that  minimal value of `resultV[k, n]` is at `k=0`

Comment: Sorry, I will be waiting for a serious reply of you.  if `k==0`, then `Veibull[x]` is meaningless. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You should redfine `Veibull[x_] = Which[x == 0, 0, True, k*x^n*Exp[-k/(n + 1)*x^(n + 1)]]`

Comment: Sorry, I have nothing to discuss with you in such an unconstructive style.

Comment: With this extension Veilbul[0]==0 takes the asymptotic limit. Your comment concerning unconstructive style is   simply negligible

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the documentation and making use of it,

```
NMinimize[{resultV[k, n], n \[Element] PositiveIntegers, k > 0}, {k, n}, 
Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 2}]
```

> `{0.00118334, {k -> 6.59549*10^-8, n -> 3}}`